# IE -- anchor tags don't work after body changed to overflow hidden and then unset

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I have a webpage that has some text and some anchor tags with external links. The page is long enough that you have to scroll (vertically) to see everything on it.
I have a modal on my page that, when clicked on, adds this the class scroll-override to the body:

```
.scroll-override {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This prevents the page from scrolling when the modal is open. When the modal is dismissed, this class is removed from the body and I can scroll again.

On IE 11/10, when the modal is dismissed, I scroll down the page to the part of the page that was not visible when the modal was open. I click on a link, and nothing happens. No error in the console, no nothing.

This only happens in IE. On the other browsers, I am able to click the links after showing and dismissing the modal, scrolling down, and clicking them.

Any ideas on why this might be?

Comment: Do the links work before you open the modal?  Do you get any other link behaviors like color change or showing the link or title?

Comment: The links work as expected before I open the modal. I get no color change (like I normally do) on hover, and the link URL doesn't show in the bottom left of my browser window.